# Is it a good idea to lazy load each component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am confused should I lazy load each component, because if this is the case, I have to make a module of each component, will it increase my app performance or just produce extra noise in my code?

If possible also give me some direction, when to use lazy loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy-loading every component individually would probably be overkill.
And lazy-loading is so much about components as modules.

The primary benefit of lazy loading is allowing your main application to load as quickly as possible, and be ready for user interaction as quickly as possible.

If you have a small application, with maybe just a couple of small modules, then lazy-loading may not make a noticeable difference. However, for a large application, with large modules and/or with many modules, it can make a large difference.

For instance, I work on an application that has 10 major modules, and a number of those have several sub-modules. We statically load the module with the landing page, and lazy-load the other 9 top-level modules.

Most users will only ever use a couple of these modules (but different users will use a different subset). This way, each user only has to incur the waiting time for loading a single module as they enter it for the first time, and never has to wait for modules to load that they're not going to use.

You'll have to decide what makes sense for your application.